# Change element in class

Tags: jquery

I want to just change one of the elements in a class with jQuery

```
.myClass
{
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

I want to programatically change this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the `myClass` class to a DOM element:

```
myElement.addClass("myClass");
```

If you want to remove the `myClass` class from a DOM element:

```
myElement.removeClass("myClass");
```

For more information, see the jQuery docs on [`hasClass`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/hasClass#class), [`addClass`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass#class), [`removeClass`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeClass#class), and [`toggleClass`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/toggleClass#class).

Comment: how do you remove an inline style?  style="..."

Comment: @coffeeaddict: You manipulate style properties of the DOM element. For example, in plain JavaScript: `myElement.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";`. Using jQuery, that would be: `myElement.css("background-color", "#fff");`.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSS for more information.

Comment: but I want to remove an entire inline style tag

Comment: @coffeeaddict: I think you would have to set each style property to its default value. For example, if you had an element with an inline style such as `style="background-color: #fff; width: 200px; height: 200px;"`, you would set the background colour to `transparent`, the width to `auto`, and the height to `auto`. In jQuery code: `myElement.css({"background-color": "transparent", "width": "auto", "height": "auto"});`.

Comment: Remember that in JavaScript, you're interacting with the *DOM* (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)—all the HTML/CSS code has been interpreted into a tree of objects—it's those objects that you have to interact with. So, removing the `style` attribute wouldn't do anything, because the styles are now part of the element object.

Answer (score 1):

This changes all .myClass elements. You can change multiple properties of the element.

```
 $(".myClass").css({'background-color':'#BBBBBB'});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass

```
$("p:last").addClass("myclass");
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery doesn't manipulate stylesheets AFAIK.  what you can do is change the `background-color` of nodes in .myClass:

```
$('.myClass').css('background-color', '#FF0000');
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove an entire inline style tag:

```
$('.myClass').removeAttr('style');
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeAttr#name